# Nginx is not serving updated files

Tags: nginx, configuration

I have configured nginx in production to server our website app, it was working fine till today. Last update I pushed was one month back, today I pushed updated code and restarted nginx but nginx is still serving old file not the updated files.

**Configuration from nginx.conf**

```
user root;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http{
    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    expires off;
    open_file_cache off;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    server{
       listen 80;
       server_name  ****.****.com;
       root /etc/nginx/www/app/public/;
       include www/app/proxy.conf;
    }
    include www/app/staticserver.conf;
 }
```

**proxy.conf**

```
location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.3.2:3003;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    access_log app;
}

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://10.0.3.2:3003;
    proxy_redirect  off;
    access_log app;
}

location /socket.io/ {
proxy_pass http://10.0.3.2:3003;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
 #js and html
location ~* ^.+\.(js)$ {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.3.2:8197;
}
#css and image and Fonts.. etc..
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|pdf|txt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|flv|swf|woff|eot|ttf|svg|html|htm|less)$ {
    proxy_pass http://10.0.3.2:8198;
}
```

**staticserver.conf**

```
#For serve java script files
server {
    listen 8197;
    server_name  10.0.3.2;
    location / {
        root /etc/nginx/www/app/public;
        access_log app_js;
    }

    #error_page  404 /404.html;
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
#For serve css | less | images |fonts..
server {
    listen 8198;
    server_name 10.0.3.2;

    location / {
        root /etc/nginx/www/app/public/;
        access_log app_others;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }
}
```

set `sendfile off;` is not working for me, any other configuration should I do to stop nginx serve old files.
I tried clear browser cache as well but no use.

Comment: Are you sure you visit this server?

Comment: yes, this is the server configuration I have set.

Comment: when I visit the app site(****.***.com) it servers old file, so I tried to visit particular file as `****.***.com/js/header.js`, first time I see old file then I re-fresh for second time then I get the updated file in browser. But then I visit the app site(****.***.com) it still serving old files.

Comment: Isn't it browser cache?

Comment: No it's not browser cache, i tried clear all my browser data from the begining, but still it is serving old file.

Comment: I have noticed the same behaviour. I updated my nginx conf, but it still uses the old conf. It actually directs me to a page that is not referenced anywhere in ``/etc/nginx`` and subdirectories, and is not running in uWSGI either.